# Tracking scroll not working with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, typescript

**I have the following code:**

```
this.currentScrollYSub = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
    .throttleTime(5)
    .subscribe(e => {
    this.scrollY = window.scrollY;
    console.log(window.scrollY); // Result: undefined
    });
```

Which works just fine on Chrome, but I noticed that on IE 10 and IE 11, it doesn't work.

How can i make this work on Internet Explorer 11?

**EDIT**

I also tried something like this:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
track(event) {
    console.debug("Scroll Event ", document.body.scrollTop); // Result: "Scroll Event 0"
}

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
track(event) {
    console.debug("Scroll Event ", this.scrollY); // Result: "Scroll Event undefined"
}
```

Comment: What does `doesn't work mean? Is the code in `subscribe(...)` called?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , I comented near console.log/debug what happens. Only for IE 10/11

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarification. Have you tried wrapping `console.log()` in a `setTimeout(...)` just to see if it's a timing issue?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Well, I just tried, i have the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY

> Internet Explorer: No support

You can use something like:

```
return {
  x: window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
  y: window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
};
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/605